# Get ancestor at certain level in hierarchy using XPath / Sitecore Query

Tags: xml, xpath, sitecore, xpath-1.0, sitecore7.2

How can I write a relative Sitecore Query (a loose version of XPath) query to return only the element "target" (i.e. the third-deep ancestor) below, when executed from a similar "contextItem" element at any depth? Due to the context in which I am executing the query, it must be relative to "contextItem" (or whatever element will be the context of the query).

In addition, I do not know the name of the item I will need to select, just the level and that it is an ancestor (as well as that it will always appear under /sitecore/content).

The execution context is Sitecore 7.2, and the query will be used to select the ancestor immediately under /sitecore/content. Thank you.

```xml
<sitecore>
  <content>
    <target>
      <level>
        <level>
         <contextItem>
         </contextItem>
        </level>
      </level>
    </target>
    <target2>
      <otherStuff/>
    </target2>
  </content>
  <system>
    <stuff/>
  </system>
  <templates>
    <otherStuff/>
  </templates>
</sitecore>
```

The following Sitecore query selects the item I'm after successfully, but also all intervening ancestors between it and the context item:

```
./ancestor::*[ancestor::*[@@key='content']]
```

These seem to work, but are inflexible and hacky:

```
./ancestor::*[@@key='home']/ancestor::*[@@key != 'sitecore' and @@key != 'content']
./ancestor::*[position() = 1 and @@key != 'sitecore' and @@key != 'content']
```

EDIT: These also work:

```
./ancestor::*[ancestor::*[@@key='content']]/.[1]
./ancestor::*[ancestor::*[parent::content]]/.[1]
```

Comment: It's great to try and ask a question as well as possible, but there's a balance - please try to avoid making too many minor edits as well.

Answer (score 2):

try this one:

```
//contextItem/ancestor::*[3]/name()
```

Comment: Thank you. That appears to work in XPath 2.0 but not 1.0. Unfortunately it also does not work in Sitecore 7.2, where I need to use this query (not your fault). Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You want to get `<target>` element given `<contextItem>` as current context element. I wonder why not :

```
./ancestor::target
```

Comment: I'm not sure what it will be called. I will update the question with that info. Thank you for answering.

Comment: @lucounu How about `./ancestor::*[parent::content]`?

Comment: That looks good... could even restrict from there with an inner [parent::sitecore], I guess, and add on something for children at any level. I'll give it a whirl. Great suggestion, thanks!

Comment: Sure, `./ancestor::*[parent::content[parent::sitecore]]` should work

Comment: For some reason it doesn't, which I chalk up to the flakiness of this XPath-lite implementation. Thank you VERY MUCH again.

Answer (score 1):

If you can rely on that being the next `target` element, then:

```
ancestor::target
```

Otherwise, if only the root element is called `sitecore`, then:

```
ancestor::target[name(../..) = "sitecore"]
```

If there's no way to identify that element other than by the level of nesting:

```
ancestor::*[../.. = /]
```

Comment: These are great suggestions, and I learned from them. Unfortunately this is a tweaked version of XPath called "Sitecore Query" and those don't work directly, though I've fiddled around trying to adapt them and feel they might work with a tweak. There is no name() available (instead a function called @@name/@@key which does not take parameters), and the syntax in the last is not accepted either.

Answer (score 1):

Is "target" of a specific template type? If not maybe you should make it and then you can simply use:

`./ancestor-or-self::*[@@templateid = '{GUID}']`

It depends on your content structure of course, but use Insert Options and restrictions so it can only ever be created at a certain level (or write your other code so you do not care which level it is at)

Answer (score 0):

I found a query that works:

```
./ancestor::*[ancestor::*[@@key='content']]/.[1]
```

Obviously, you would adjust if you might have an item with a key of "content" in the hierarchy deeper than at the second level; you could, for example, use @@id with the GUID of the /sitecore/content item.

There is something a bit funky with the XPath index-based queries in Sitecore--using an index of 1 seems to often return the top three items (/sitecore, /sitecore/Content, and /sitecore/Content/whatever). Using the index-based query format above will return the item at the specified level *plus two*--so in this case, it'd return the third-ancestor, a child of /sitecore/Content, which is what I am after.

I will be interested to learn a better way of doing this.